# How to write this logical statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

how to write the logical expression for this? Either ... or... if .

For example: Either you win or lose if you play the game.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p$ then $q$ is equivalent to $q$ if $p$.

so if you let $w$, $l$, $p$ be boolean variables representing win, lose, and play, you could write:

$p \implies (w \lor l)$

Comment: thank you! I'm just confused on what I have read here. the exclusive or.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for common logical symbols that are used to represent these connectives? If so, you can use $\lor$ for "or" and $\impliedby$ for "if". Your example sentence can be written as

"You play the game $\implies$ you win $\lor$ you lose"

You should really avoid using these symbols in normal writing though; they should be reserved for making mathematical claims unambiguous (e.g. $\lor$ denotes inclusive or, while "or" in English can be either inclusive or exclusive).

Comment: Thank you so much! :)